# Get Vim on Mac terminal to copy to the clipboard

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

I'm using Vim on a Mac, installed via homebrew, version 8.0.

Vim --version shows +clipboard, and -xterm_clipboard.

I've tried

```
 set clipboard=unnamed
```

in .vimrc

But I cannot get yanks to go on to the system clipboard. What do I do?

Comment: are you sure noone is overriding your clipboard variable? what does `echo &clipboard` give you?

Comment: That is the strangest thing ever. After typing `echo &clipboard` in the bash terminal then suddenly, after years of not working, yanks are going to the clipboard in Vim. Thinking that it could be because I'd made another change in .vimrc that affected things I reverted to a previous .vimrc (all in git) and yanks are still working with the previous .vimrc that wasn't working. Sometimes computers are really strange. I'll move on. Thanks for your comment, somehow it fixed things but I've no idea how.

Comment: Actually I did more than type `echo &clipboard` in the bash terminal, I also typed into command in vim, I got back 'unnamed', but after that Vim yanks are going to the Mac clipboard.

Comment: Well not this is really insane. In another terminal instance it does not work.

Comment: So I now have two terminal windows open on a Mac. In one yanks go to the clipboard, and if I type `echo &clipboard` into the command section I get back 'unnamed'. In the other yanks do not go to the clipboard and if I type `echo &clipboard` into command I get back nothing. Both are using the same .vimrc with `set clipboard=unnamed` configured. What could the problem be?

Comment: try `:verbose set clipboard?`. It should tell you when and where this variable was last set.

Answer (score 1):

It should "just work" on MacVim. One of the reasons I'm using it is for its OSX integration, including clipboard.

`brew install macvim`

`mvim` defaults to graphical mode. To run it in terminal mode:

`mvim -v`

In the past, I had an alias for `vim` -> `mvim -v` which handles most cases. These days I use the following script in `~/bin/vim`, which is in my `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mvim -v "$@"
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like something is overriding your clipboard setting after loading your vimrc.

try `:verbose set clipboard?`. It should tell you when and where this variable was last set.

[This guide](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Debug_unexpected_option_settings) gives you a bunch of hints on what to do to figure out what's going on and fix the problem

Comment: I rebooted and now all Vim instances are yanking to the clipboard. When I tried `:verbose set clipboard?` it says it's set to unamed and it got it from .vimrc. So it's now working, even though it wasn't before, and I'm using the same version of .vimrc I had before and stored in Git. It's working, but I'm confused about why it's working. I'll just put it down to 'one of those things' and move on.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the guide by the way.